# Integal - work - vector

Tags: integration

Can you guys help me to solve this question? I'm trying a lot, but I can't continue.

Imagine a sequence of events, held in each cylinder of an internal combustion cylinder engine. Each piston moves up and down and is connected by a pivot arm to the crankshaft. P (t) and V (t) are the pressure and volume within a cylinder at time t, where a <= t <= b is the time required for a complete cycle. For example, in one stage, called induction or aspiration, the mixture of air and gasoline at atmospheric pressure is drawn into the cylinder by the inlet valve as the piston moves down. Then, the piston quickly compresses the mixture with the valve closed, in the compression stage. The work performed by the piston during a cycle of a four-stroke motor is given by W = Integral (P dv), in a curve C in a PV plane. The problem is to calculate the work done by the engine pistons when

**P = (y - x²) i + (z-y²) j + (x-z²) k**

where C is the helix **V (t) = ti + t²j + t³** , with (0.0.0) to (1,1,1)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$W=\int_{(0,0,0)}^{(1,1,1)}Pdv=\int_0^1\left((t^2-t^2)i+(t^3-t^4)j+(t-t^6)k\right).(i+2tj+3t^2k)dt$$